# AG Grid, column chooser with parent groups, but without visible parent groups in the grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In the demo page from ag-grid we could see that we got a column chooser with groups:

[image]

but giving this configuration to ag-grid, it creates those groups in the grid itself, you could see that in above screen we got Participant, Game of Choice, and bellow these we got the children columns.

What I am trying to do is actually to have the same groups in the column chooser, but to have a flat list of columns in the grid without Parent Categories displayed.

Does anyone know maybe there is some boolean in the ag-grid props that could turn on/off this setting, or another way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that i found till now it is to do a small hack with css. Basically you just hide all header rows, except the last row:

[image]